# Real Time Collaboration free Java IDE

Tags: java, ide

I am looking for real-time collaborative Java IDE, which is light and fast. Me and my friend are working on same project, so any suggestions.? It should be easy to operate.

Answer (score 5):

There's a plugin for Eclipse called [Saros](http://www.saros-project.org) that supports collaborative editing.

Answer (score 3):

got it..[.compilr](http://compilr.com/) it is.

Comment: Does it support real-time collaboration? Could not find that feature in their description.

Comment: I checked it. there is some slight delay, otherwise its fine

Comment: It is not free. There is no even free trial